# How to ensure repeatability of results in multi-process computation

Tags: c, multiprocessing, mpi, shared-memory, semaphore

I have multiple `MPI` processes running in parallel all these processes access a shared memory and performs following operations :

```
sem_wait(sem);   
shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(int), 0777)) < 0)        
shm = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
printf("process id = %d, shm = ",rank, *shm);//rank from MPI_Comm_rank()
new_val = *shm+1; 
*shm = new_val; 
sem_post(sem);
```

This code is a part of a much bigger code which I cannot put here so I have given only a small part which I think needs to be changed.

I get the follwing result (for first run):

```
process id = 1 shm = 1
process id = 2 shm = 2
process id = 3 shm = 3
process id = 4 shm = 4
process id = 5 shm = 5
```

I get the follwing result (for second run):

```
process id = 2 shm = 1
process id = 3 shm = 2
process id = 1 shm = 3
process id = 5 shm = 4
process id = 4 shm = 5
```

Similarly different results for different runs.

Is it possible to change the code in a way that it generates same value everytime?

I am working on C in linux environment.

I badly need repeatability in my code. Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: It's possible, but it requires more code.  Do you really need to do this?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth yes I badly need repeatability in my code. Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: If you want an exact order of execution each time maybe a parallel model isn't optimal for the problem you're trying to solve. A correctly written  parallel program will produce the same result regardless of the order in which the operating system schedules the threads and processes. The general solution to get exact ordering of operations is to use a single thread/process. You can make threads behave in an ordered way, but it requires thought and care on every lock and operation and will most likely remove parallelism.

Comment: Also never ever use the `shm*` or `sem_*` library calls without checking their return value. They can be interrupted by signals, e.g. and you are never to get a stable application like this.

Comment: @JensGustedt yes I am checking the return values in the actual code. I avoided them here for simplicity sake. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into whether or not this is a very good idea, it seems like you want deterministic ordering of the system calls between your various processes.  That's quite achievable with MPI--for example:

```
for (int ii = 0; ii < MPI_Comm_size(); ii++) {
    if ii == MPI_Comm_rank() {
        // attach shmem
    }
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
}
```

This will make the processes "take turns" attaching to shared memory.